# How to sucessfully import an .ova vm exported from ovirt/kvm (Red Hat OS)?

Tags: linux, redhat, kvm-virtualization, qemu, ovirt

So, I was given an .ova file. This is exported from a server using a combination of KVM/QEMU and ovirt technologie - the server runs RedHat and I want to import this .ova file into vmware or virtualbox for some reasons and that is the only solution.

I already extracted the ova - this gave me an ovf file and two raw files. Tried to convert them with qemu-img (using `qemu-img convert -f raw -O vmdk disk1.raw disk1.vmdk` and similar command) into .vmdk and .qcow2. I tried to import every each one of them into vmware/vbox, as well as the .ovf file, but a "No Operating System found" message appears (I did not try to load an OS into that, which may be wrong?).

What is the best way to load the .ova disk image into vmware?

Thanks a lot, it's kind of an urgency.